# Extract names between Academic Degree Variances using Regex Python

Tags: python, regex, extract, regex-group

This code is having trouble extracting complete names from between academic degrees, for example, Dr. Richard, MM or Dr. Bobby Richard Klaus, MM or Richar, MM. The academic degrees is not only Dr but also Dr., Dra., Prof., Drs, Prof. Dr., M.Ag and ME.

The output would be like this

**The Goal Result**

| Complete Names | Names (?) |
| --- | --- |
| Dr. RICHARD, MM | Richard |
| Dra. BOBBY Richard Klaus, MM | Bobby Richard Klaus |
| Richard, MM | Richard |

but actually, the result is expected to like this

**Actual Result**

| Complete Names | Names |
| --- | --- |
| Dr. Richard, MM | Richard |
| Dra. Bobby Richard Klaus, MM | Richard Klaus |
| Richard, MM | Richard, MM |

with this code

```
def extract_names(text):
   """ fix capitalize """
   text = re.sub(r"(_|-)+"," ", text).title()
   """ find name between whitespace and comma """
   text = re.findall("\s[A-Z]\w+(?:\s[A-Z]\w+?)?\s(?:[A-Z]\w+?)?[\s\.\,\;\:]", text)
   text = ' '.join(text[0].split(","))
```

then there is another problem, error

> 11    text = ' '.join(text[0].split(","))
> 12    return text
> 13    # def extract_names(text):

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Maybe all you need is to remove `Dr.` and `, MM`? `text.replace('Dr.','').replace(', MM','').strip()`

Comment: Why would `Dr. Bobby Richard Klaus, MM` become `Richard Klaus` ?

Comment: I think is because of this ```re.findall("\s[A-Z]\w+(?:\s[A-Z]\w+?)?\s(?:[A-Z]\w+?)?[\s\.\,\;\:]", text)```

Comment: Could you explain the different meanings of "Target" and "Expected"? For me both sound as if they should be the result of the transformation and that must be wrong.

Comment: What is the pattern you need to remove/extract? With regex, you must be very specific. Saying "and etc." you assume there is no way to write a finite pattern. What is the pattern here?

Comment: remove academic degrees @WiktorStribiżew, academic degrees have a lot of variances, thank you, i try to make my questions more detail

Comment: And you need to specify all those variances, else, we cannot help you. Your pattern requirements must be outlined in the question. Regex has no notion of `\p{AcademicVariances}`, you know. Also, what is expected for `Dra. Bobby Richard Klaus, MM`? Which table is the expected result? Lower or upper?

Comment: the upper table is the goal result, but expected result is the lower table ,  thanks a lot your guide for my questions

Comment: Maybe, what you mean is "actual" result, instead of expected result?

Comment: `re.sub(r'^(?:\s*(?:Dr[sa]?|Prof|M\.Ag|M[EM])\.?)+\s*|\s*,(?:\s*(?:Dr[sa]?|Prof|M\.Ag|M[EM])\.?)+$', '', text, flags=re.I)`? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kjbh4o/1),

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot your regex is awesome,  the solutions is add all the variances in the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
ads = r'(?:Dr[sa]?|Prof|M\.Ag|M[EM])\.?'
result = re.sub(fr'^(?:\s*{ads})+\s*|\s*,(?:\s*{ads})+$', '', text, flags=re.I)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kjbh4o/1).

The `(?:Dr[sa]?|Prof|M\.Ag|M[EM])\.?` pattern matches `Dr`, `Drs`, `Dra`, `Prof`, `M.Ag`, `ME`, `MM` optionally followed with a `.`.

The `^(?:\s*{ads})+\s*|\s*,(?:\s*{ads})+$` main pattern matches

- `^(?:\s*{ads})+\s*` - start of string, then one or more sequences of zero or more whitespaces and `ads` pattern and then zero or more whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `\s*,` - zero or more whitespaces and a comma
- `(?:\s*{ads})+` - one or more repetitions of zero or more whitespaces and `ads` pattern
- `$` - end of string